# Airpods use on macOS resets double tap action

Tags: macos, bluetooth, airpods

I use my apple airpods with lots of different platforms. On windows, iOS & Android everything is fine.

On macOS everything works too but it resets the double tap action to next track on both L/R (I like to have play/pause)

I have second generation airpods. Does anyone else know why this is happening and how to stop it?

FYI: I use tooth fairy on my mac to quickly connect and disconnect and am running the current 10.4.5 build of mojave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AirPods double tap settings are unique to each Apple device. You’ll need to adjust the double tap settings on your Mac directly to mimic what you have on iOS.

I personally have different settings on my iPhone and Mac, but that’s a personal decision.

It seems like non-apple devices inherit compatible settings (pause/play, next track, but not Siri etc.) from your iOS double tap settings.

[Features That Work on Android](https://www.macrumors.com/guide/airpods-android/)

> Out of the box, AirPods functionality on Android is quite limited, but the double tap feature works. When you double tap on one of the AirPods, it will play or pause the music. If you've customized your AirPods using an iOS device, next track and previous track gestures will also work, but Siri won't, nor will "Hey Siri" on AirPods 2 as that requires an Apple device.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise the settings where unique to each apple device. I therefore believe that non apple devices therefore just use the most recent active profile. Which will explain this. I will edit settings on my mac

Comment: Glad it was helpful! Would appreciate you accepting my answer. Let me know what you find out about how non apple devices work. Cheers

Comment: Hi, is this explanation still relevant today ? (iOS 17 and Airpod firmware 6A300) My Airpods 3rd gen keep resetting the setting to double tap to mute, despite how many time I change the setting in ALL the devices connected (iphone, Mac, iPad)